# How should I use dynamic filtering with SQLAchemy coerretctly?

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, fastapi, repository-pattern

I stuck in bunch of errors with dynamic filtering in SQLAlchemy,
I tried to make a Repository Pattern in FastAPI app.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import models


class MessageRepository:
    def __init__(self, db:Session):
        self.db = db

    def get_query(self, **filters):
        return self.db.query(models.Messages).filter(getattr(models.Messages, attr) == value for attr, value in filters.items()).all()

    def inbox(self, user):
        return self.get_query(filters={'receiver': user})
```

then I tried to use class "MessageRepository" in my FastAPI app;

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, HTTPException, Depends, APIRouter
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List
from .. import schemas
from ..data_access.database import get_db
from ..data_access.crud import MessageRepository


router = APIRouter(prefix='/msg', tags=['Messages'])


@router.get('/', response_model=list[schemas.MessageBack])
def get_inbox(db:Session=Depends(get_db), user="9123456789"):
    msgs = MessageRepository(db).inbox(user)
    return msgs
```

the actual error is:
**sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected**, got <generator object MessageRepository.get_query.. at 0x00000229823675B0>.

in the meanwhile, when I'm trying this Repository without dynamic filtering in queries, everything works!

```
class MessageRepository:
    def __init__(self, db:Session):
        self.db = db

    def get_all_msgs(self, user):
        return self.db.query(models.Messages).filter(models.Messages.receiver == user).all()



@router.get('/', response_model=list[schemas.MessageBack])
def get_inbox(db:Session=Depends(get_db), user="9123456789"):
    msgs = MessageRepository(db).get_all_msgs(user)
    return msgs
```

How I can fix this?!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`query.filter_by(**filters)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter_by), since it does exacly what you wants and accepts the filters as keyword arguments. Then, you don’t need the `getattr` or the generator.

Answer (score 0):

`getattr(models.Messages, attr) == value for attr, value in filters.items()` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), and SQLAlchemy does not know how to use this in a `filter` method. The solution is to use the unpacking operator (`*`) to get the filter expressions from the generator expression.  Like this:

```py
self.db.query(models.Messages).filter(
    *(getattr(models.Messages, attr) == value for attr, value in filters.items())
).all()
```